# how to input 2 value from each column to one column in another table

Tags: php, laravel, crud

i try to input value of first_name and last_name from table students to column name of table users
here is my studentcontroller

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new User;
        $user->name = $request->first_name&&$request->last_name;
        $user->save();

        $student = new Santri;
        $student->user_id = $user->id;
        $student->first_name = $request->get('first_name');
        $student->last_name = $request->get('last_name');
        $student->save();

 return redirect()->route('student.index');
    }
```

then the result value='1' in column name at table user

how to get value first_name and last_name sorted to column name in table user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use &&, use php's concatenation operator.

```
$user->name = $request->first_name . $request->last_name;
```

The reason why you're getting 1 as a result is because you're using the && Logical operator. Because php is very weakly typed it assumes anything that isn't a null or a 0 is "True", and by comparing "True" && "True" you get "True" which is 1

Comment: how to add space between them?

Comment: Concatenate another space between them
$request->first_name . " " . $request->last_name

Comment: what that mean @shib?

Comment: Concatenation means you're adding words together. Take 1 + 1 which will equal 2. Whereas with contatenation '1' . '1' will equal 11, since you're just merging it together.